# MySQL query to select rows where one column matches and one column does not

Tags: mysql

Here are my table setups

Results_class

```
CREATE TABLE appfilter.results_class (
 activity varchar(120) NOT NULL,
 class varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (activity, class)
)
```

Users

```
CREATE TABLE appfilter.user (
user varchar(15) NOT NULL,
name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
activity_full varchar(200) NOT NULL,
activity varchar(125) NOT NULL,
class varchar(125) NOT NULL
)
```

The results i want is simple. I want to see all rows where activity matches and class does not.

**Example**

Results_class

```
activity                        class
com.google.android.apps.plus    com.google.android.apps.circles.realtimechat.ConversationListActivity
com.google.android.apps.plus    com.google.android.apps.plus.phone.ConversationListActivity
```

Users

```
activity                        class
com.google.android.apps.plus    com.google.android.apps.circles.realtimechat.ConversationListActivity
```

*I need it to select this missing activity/class which is*

```
activity                        class
com.google.android.apps.plus    com.google.android.apps.plus.phone.ConversationListActivity<br>
```

I have tried this and it gives me all the activity/classes. Now if i can just remove the ones already in users thats what i need.

```
SELECT
  rc.activity, rc.class
FROM results_class rc
  INNER JOIN user b
    ON b.activity = rc.activity
```

Comment: is this not possible, or am i not explaining properly?

Comment: Your title seems simple, but you've got lots of detail here. I'd suggest simplifying this to the shortest reproducible example and you'll get help much faster. Or/and set up an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Have you tried extending your join criteria, e.g. `INNER JOIN user b ON (b.activity = rc.activity AND b.class != rc.class)`?

Comment: Yes but that is bringing back activity/class names already in users table for some reason.

Comment: Here is a fiddle if that helps http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a2dd/1/0

Comment: check my solution.. easy effective and simple left join

Comment: @Bignadad hey did you give it a shot..?

Comment: @SumeetSharma your query is incorrect. see my answer for the correct output.

Comment: @JohnRuddell i can see only one row in the result..whereas there are 2 rows in the result_class table which are not present in the user table.. namely the drumanalyzer and Main activity

Comment: ok.. reading through the comments I found out a crucial piece of informaton missing from the question ..
"Yes look at my fiddle though. If there is a activity in results_class and not in users its bringing it back too. I only need matching activities to bring non matching classes"..

Comment: @SumeetSharma you have it wrong.. The activity has to match. So after finding a matching activity you then need to find an unmatching class

Comment: @JohnRuddell Yeah considered that.. check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a subquery with exists

```
SELECT  rc.activity, rc.class
FROM results_class rc
JOIN users c on c.activity = rc.activity
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(   SELECT 1
    FROM user b 
    WHERE b.class = rc.class
)
```

So basically you get all of the results_class activities when joined to users.. then filter out the classes that are in results_class but not in users.

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a2dd/17)

Answer (score 1):

Try this .. The below query emulates the MINUS operation ie matches all in class a which are not in b.

```
SELECT a.activity,a.class FROM results_class a 
left join user b on (a.activity = b.activity and a.class = b.class) 
where b.class is null
```

Working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a2dd/46/0)

**AFTER EDIT**
considering the missed information in the question 
"If there is a activity in results_class and not in users its bringing it back too. I only need matching activities to bring non matching classes"

```
select a1.activity,a1.class from (select a.activity,a.class FROM results_class a 
left join user b on (a.activity = b.activity and a.class = b.class) 
where b.class is null) a1 inner join user b1 on a1.activity = b1.activity
```

Comment: you do realize this is incorrect right? im not the downvoter.. but you should try and fix your query before you get more downvotes!

Comment: "Yes look at my fiddle though. If there is a activity in results_class and not in users its bringing it back too. I only need matching activities to bring non matching classes"

This information is missing in the question .. I got it from your conversation .. will edit my answer relevantly then...